# How to convert Amazon MWS credentials to SP-API creds

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws, amazon-selling-partner-api

[Here are the seemingly clear instructions from Amazon.](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/en-US/use-case-guides/authorization-api-use-case-guide/authorization-api-use-case-guide-v1.md#tutorial-migrate-an-amazon-mws-authorization-to-a-selling-partner-api-application)

Simply send the following:  sellingPartnerId, developerId, and mwsAuthToken

I do this with `httparty` like so:

```
query = {
  sellingPartnerId: "A3Kxxxxx",
  developerId: "753xxxx",
  mwsAuthToken: "amzn.mws.8abxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx",
}
```

and then

```
send = HTTParty.get("https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/authorization/v1/authorizationCode", 
  query: query
)
```

This returns the following error:

```
{"errors"=>
  [{"message"=>"Access to requested resource is denied.",
    "code"=>"MissingAuthenticationToken"}]}
```

I've adjusted the call everyway I've seen. I've read the following articles:
[This](https://marco-tibaldeschi.medium.com/amazon-sp-api-auth-auth-demystified-ab3bc746729b)
[This](https://vdanyliv.medium.com/amazon-selling-partner-api-spapi-how-to-quickly-and-simply-integrate-with-new-api-part-2-59d7458f24fe)

Paged through the 695 issues on github for this API and still no luck.. I've adjusted my query to this with no luck either:

```
query = {
  grant_type: "client_credentials",
  sellingPartnerId: "A3K98Oxxxxxx",
  developerId: "753xxxxxxxx",
  mwsAuthToken: "amzn.mws.8abxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx",
  client_id: "amzn1.application-oa2-client.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  client_secret: "a473e76XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  scope: "sellingpartnerapi::migration"
}
```

Nothing I've tried has worked.. Any suggestions? Has anyone actually migrated their MWS to SP-API credential successfully?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately the specific Amazon docs that you link to don't tell the whole story. There are a few other requirements you'll need in order to get the `authorizationCode` response that you're looking for:

#### Amazon OAuth Token

You'll need an access token from Amazon's OAuth API (an entirely different API). You can use [the `grantless` workflow](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/en-US/developer-guide/SellingPartnerApiDeveloperGuide.md#grantless-operations) for this, since in your case the user hasn't actually authorized the SP-API yet:

```
POST https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token

body: {
    grant_type: 'client_credentials',
    scope: 'sellingpartnerapi::migration',
    client_id: 'amzn1.application-oa2-client.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    client_secret: 'a473e76XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
}
```

This will return an `access_token` that you'll need for your actual migration request to `https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/authorization/v1/authorizationCode`. The response will look something like:

```
{
    "access_token": "Atc|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "scope": "sellingpartnerapi::migration",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600
}
```

**Important:** Take the `access_token` value from that response and add it as an `x-amz-access-token` header to your `/authorization/v1/authorizationCode` request.

#### Sign Your Request

This is the actual reason behind the error you're receiving. An unsigned request will not include the "authorization token" that you're being prompted for.

You'll need to sign your request using Amazon's `SigV4` signing mechanism. It looks like you're using Ruby (HTTParty), so you can use the `aws-sdk`'s [Aws::Sigv4::Signer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/Sigv4/Signer.html) for this. You'll need to have setup IAM credentials as documented in [the generic developer guide](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/en-US/developer-guide/SellingPartnerApiDeveloperGuide.md#creating-and-configuring-iam-policies-and-entities), and those credentials being provided to your `Aws::Sigv4::Signer` somehow (hardcoding, env vars, [Aws::SharedCredentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/SharedCredentials.html), etc.)

Request signing will result in a few proprietary headers being added to your request. Once this is done, you should have all that you need to make the request successfully.

Comment: No way!! are you serious?? Wow, how in the world did you figure this out?? Thank you soo much, I'll try right now.

Comment: In fairness, these requirements are mentioned in the generic developer guide I linked. The problem with these docs is that there's usually 3-5 ways to do any one thing, and little to no documented correlation as to when to do something and why. Your original doc link being a prime example. 

Far too much trial-and-error is what got me this far, and I haven't made it much further with this API.

Comment: Yeah, the amazon docs are absolutely horrible

Comment: I'm currently on hold with an amazon support staff to help me understand the sp-api docs. So bad...